# Use JAVA timer in the background without causing any lag in the UI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, timer

I am making a java application that send data automatically to my remote server.
What i need is to insert data without feeling lag to the end user. the remote db update part should be run in the background. i tried swingworker, thread but nothing worked. still lags my app. here is what i have done so far

```
public class uploader extends Thread {

    static Socket socket;
    static Timer ttt;

    public void run() {
        try {
            ttt = new Timer(15000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try {

                        socket = new Socket("192.168.10.1", 3306);                   

//upload
                        ResultSet rs = DB.search("select query,id FROM general_log where state = 0 order by id asc");
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            try {
                                socket = new Socket("192.168.10.1", 3306);
                                DB2.acknowledge(rs.getString(1));
                                DB.acknowledge("update general_log set state = 1 where id = '" + rs.getString(2) + "'");

                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                                System.out.println("error");
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e3) {
                        System.out.println("error");
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            ttt.start();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

And i run it on the start up

```
Thread upl = new Thread(new uploader());
upl.start();
```

every 15 second local data should upload to the remote server. but in here my UI lags ever 15 sec when the timer runs.

how can i do it without causing a lag?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code in a Swing Timer executes on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which prevents the GUI from updating itself until the task finishes. You should be creating a separate Thread to execute a long running task. So basically your code is reversed. You should not start the Thread when your application starts. Instead you start the Timer. Then the Timer will start the Thread to do the server update.

Comment: Hi. Thanx. but doesn't it create new threads for every 15 second?

Comment: Why on Earth are you creating a new `Socket` for every row of the `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 2):

You could optimize your SQL query with index, that's for sure.

Besides regarding main question wouldn't it be better to use Timer Task that starts up in `new Handler()` ?

===========================================

for example instead of class create a method:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private TimerTask timerTask;
private Timer timer = new Timer();



...

    public void sendBackgroundData() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(() -> {

DO YOUR CODE

                    }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 2000);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i am new to this. how can i implement that?

Comment: @UthpalaBandara, A TimerTask is the same as a Timer, except it runs in a different Thread. Read the API for the TimerTask. You can also search the forum/web for examples that use that class.

Comment: @Jawegiel Can you add the imports as well please? thank you.

Comment: Mea culpa, I got confused it's Android way to create async task calling piece of code every X sec. In plain Java should be something similar. Sorry buddy!

Comment: In plain Java, it’s `java.util.TimerTask`, but using that old class is not recommended. Instead, the preferable solution is `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`, acquired best via `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)` (one is the number of threads). Then, use either, `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay`.